# Probability of almost correct order

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I'm a teacher handing tests back to seven students.

If I do it with my eyes closed, what's the probability I hand exactly 5 of the tests back to the correct students?

There are many possible ways this could happen, and if my understanding of probability is correct, the sum of the individual probabilities of all possibilities where I hand exactly 5 back to the correct student yields the answer I'm looking for.

One such probability (hand out the first two tests incorrectly): 
$$\frac{6}{7}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}
\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1} $$

Another probability (hand out the last two tests incorrectly): 
$$\frac{1}{7}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}
\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1} $$

One more: 
$$\frac{1}{7}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{3}
\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1} $$

We can simplify these probabilities to: 
$$\frac{6\cdot5}{7!}, \frac{1\cdot1}{7!}, \frac{4\cdot2}{7!} $$

More generally, we can think about all possible times when the two incorrect letters might occur, and deduce that the sum of all possible probabilities is:

$$\frac{6(5+4+3+2+1)+5(4+3+2+1)+4(3+2+1)+3(2+1)+2(1)+1(1)}{7!}$$

Is this really the answer? I really feel like I missed something that would simplify this answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are $$\binom{7}{2}$$ ways to choose the $2$ students who receive the wrong tests. Obviously, the only way for this to happen is if their tests are switched.

There are $7!$ total ways to hand back the tests, so the probability is

$$\frac{\binom{7}{2}}{7!} = \frac{1}{2 \cdot 5!} = \boxed{\frac{1}{240}}$$

A related question would be: what is the probability that you hand back no tests to the correct students? If this interests you, you should read about [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: and read about [rencontres numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers)

Comment: Thanks, but I guess more to the point of my question, where did my logic go wrong?

Comment: @zthomas.nc Each of your probabilities is incorrect. The first, for example, should not be $$\frac{6}{7}\cdot\frac{5}{6}$$ but rather $$\frac{1}{7}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$$ because if the first two are the wrong ones, the first student *has* to get the second student's exam. I said in my answer that "the only way for this to happen is if their tests are switched", which was getting at the same thing. I hope that clears things up :)

Answer (score 1):

Or as another way way of reaching @Zubin Mukerjee correct answer:

There are $\binom{7}{5}$ ways to pick the 5 students who get their proper papers, and only one way to give the remaining two the wrong papers...

Edit to respond to OP's comment...

Well, consider the first way you enumerate.. Your first two terms give the total probability of getting the first two wrong, **including times when the first two got papers from #3 through #7**.  But that's not possible, since you then give #3 through #7 their correct papers...

Comment: Thanks, but I guess more to the point of my question, where did my logic go wrong?

Comment: Oh gee, good point. Thanks.